# A move symantics problem with a match statement containing an "otherwise" clause

Tags: rust

## A summary of the problem

I am trying to write a match statement in Rust.

Here's a minimal version of what it looks like:

```
let optional_1 = Some(String::from("has_value_here"));
let optional_2 = Some(String::from("also_has_value_here"));

match (optional_1, optional_2) { // The Option<> is moved here

    // The contents of the option are moved here
    (Some(string_1), Some(string_2)) => {
        do_something_with_string_1_and_string_2(string_1, string_2);
    }

    // A "catch-all" case / "otherwise clause"
    _ => {

        // We want to provide feedback to the user if any of the optional
        // values are missing.

        // This statement does not compile
        if let None = optional_1 {
            println!("optiona_1 doesn't have a value, but this is required!");
        }

        // This statement does not compile
        if let None = optional_2 {
            println!("optiona_2 doesn't have a value, but this is required!");
        }
    }
}
```

## Why it doesn't work

There are two statements which do not compile. The reason is fairly obvious. The ownership of the variables `optional_1` and `optional_2` has been moved into the match statement. That means they don't exist inside the `_` (catch-all) statement. This is somewhat counter-intuitive, because the catch-all branch is actually part of the same match statement. But there's no way to refer to the variables there, because they don't get destructured with names.

Put another way, since I am not totally sure that explanation is clear:

We create a new tuple object here:

```
match (optional_1, optional_2)
```

That transfers ownership of the two `Option<>`s to an anonymous `tuple` object.

That tuple is then immediatly destructured as part of a `match` statement. If it doesn't match the first branch, ie one or both of the `Option<>`s contains `None`, then it will match with `_`. Since `_` doesn't assign any new variable names to the tuple, or its contents, there is no variable name to refer to the data contained within the tuple anymore.

## How to fix it? (Some possible leads for ideas...)

There's a couple of ideas I had, none of which are really suitable.

Firstly, we could change the tuple so that the match operates with references. This is the wrong solution, because the function `do_something_with_string_1_and_string_2` should move the values which it takes as arguments. It should "consume" or "own" the data passed to it. (Otherwise we have to call `.clone()` somewhere, and that shouldn't be needed, since there is a single execution path all the way from the code which exists well before this match statement, all the way deep into the logic of `do_something_with_string_1_and_string_2`.

In other words, we never need a clone of the data along the branch followed by `(Some(string_1), Some(string_2))`, so we shouldn't have to add it here just for the `_` branch to work.

---

An alternative would be to move the user-feedback `println!` statements outside of the match statement, and to write them using

```
if optional_1.is_none() { 

}

if optional_2.is_none() {

}

// then

if optional_1.is_some() && optional_2.is_some() {
    // match statement goes here, now pointless
    // because this might as well have been (see
    // below)
    match ...
}

// or

if let Some(string_1) = optional_1 && let Some(string_2) = optional_2 {
    // this is likely a better alternative, no match statement here
}
```

This option isn't great, because the `if` logic ends up repeated. There is 1 `if` for each field which might be missing, then there is a duplicate `if let` which combines everything together. This can't be part of an `else` statement, because we want to emit feedback to the user for each missing field.

---

A final thought would be to provide names to destructure the tuple rather than using `_`.

```
match (optional_1, optional_2) {

    (Some(...), Some(...)) => {
        // ...
    }

    (None, Some(_)) => {
        println!("optional_1 doesn't have a value, but this is required!");
    }

    (Some(_), None) => {
        println!("optional_2 doesn't have a value, but this is required!");
    }

    (None, None) => {
        println!("optional_1 doesn't have a value, but this is required!");
        println!("optional_2 doesn't have a value, but this is required!");
    }
```

This is obviously not a good idea, because as the number of `Option<>` increases, the number of cases to cover explodes, but I included it because it might inspire someone to consider a way of condensing this approach... somehow?

## Final comments

In the real production code I am writing, the number of `Option<>`s is not just 2, but up to (currently) 7. Now it is clear why some of the suggested ideas just aren't feasible.

Answer (score 3):

You can instead of `_` destruct the values and give them names:

```rust
match (optional_1, optional_2) {
    // The Option<> is moved here

    // The contents of the option are moved here
    (Some(string_1), Some(string_2)) => {
        do_something_with_string_1_and_string_2(string_1, string_2);
    }

    // A "catch-all" case / "otherwise clause"
    (optional_1, optional_2) => {
        // We want to provide feedback to the user if any of the optional
        // values are missing.

        // This statement does not compile
        if let None = optional_1 {
            println!("optiona_1 doesn't have a value, but this is required!");
        }

        // This statement does not compile
        if let None = optional_2 {
            println!("optiona_2 doesn't have a value, but this is required!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is similar to the idea I just thought of, I've posted it above, but not quite right because `string_1` and `string_2` in your second match branch are still `Option` types

Comment: Ah, I see, you just named them `string1` and `string2` but they *are* still options. Ok it's the same

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant That was just typo, I renamed them now.

Answer (score 1):

After some further consideration I came up with this slightly bizzare solution.

```
let optional_1 = Some(String::from("has_value_here"));
let optional_2 = Some(String::from("also_has_value_here"));

match (optional_1, optional_2) {

    (Some(string_1), Some(string_2)) => {
        do_something_with_string_1_and_string_2(string_1, string_2);
    }

    // This is still a "catch-all" case / "otherwise clause"
    (optional_1, optional_2) => {

        // Weird, but it works...

        // We can now do this
        if let None = optional_1 {
            println!("optiona_1 doesn't have a value, but this is required!");
        }

        // Obviously can also do this
        if optional_2.is_none() {
            println!("optiona_2 doesn't have a value, but this is required!");
        }
    }
}
```

It should be kind of obvious *why* this works, although it's a very weird solution because we are matching on some "thing" and then the final branch of the match is just "if thing is thing" meaning if "thing" "is itself" which is obviously, and trivially true...

It's the same as doing this...

```
let thing = String::from("thing");
let optional = Some(thing);

if ... {

}
else if let optional = optional {
    // true, duh ...
}
```